# Make Simulation Nodes run slower?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

Is there a way to make Simulation Nodes skip every other frame, or perhaps run only on every Nth frame? I feel like I'm really close to figuring this out but can't quite get there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a setup for a simple simulation, that allows to specify how many steps (frames) to skip:

[image]

In Blender 4.0 onward you can use the "Skip" output of the Simulation Output to simplify the setup. Keep in mind however, skipping the simulation step won't allow you to update the $i$, so you need to make the check stateless like so:

[image]

The problem with this setup is that it doesn't keep the $i$'s equivalent, *Frame*, small, and so after frame $2^{24} = 16777216$ it will start to malfunction due to floating point accuracy being worse than $1$ above this value. This is an unlikely problem, but [happens](http://the-witness.net/news/2022/02/a-shader-trick/) in the industry.

Anyway, here's the result:

[image]

Unfortunately currently the *Delta Time* input doesn't give you the delta time since last actually evaluated simulation step, so you need to multiply the scale of the offset by the $1 + $ *skip edges* if you don't want the skipped simulations to not lag behind.